# Relacionamento entre 4 tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho as tabelas:

```
-- NORTE --
create table tb_indices_norte(
id_norte int not null auto_increment,
localidade varchar(30),
sem_epi int not null,
totOvos smallint,
num_pos smallint,
num_inst smallint, 
ipo decimal(5,1),
ido decimal(5,1),
ano varchar(4),
primary key(id_norte)) default charset = utf8; 

-- SUL --
create table tb_indices_sul(
id_sul int not null auto_increment,
localidade varchar(30),
sem_epi int not null,
totOvos smallint,
num_pos smallint,
num_inst smallint, 
ipo decimal(5,1),
ido decimal(5,1),
ano varchar(4),
primary key(id_sul)) default charset = utf8;

-- LESTE --
create table tb_indices_leste(
id_leste int not null auto_increment,
localidade varchar(30),
sem_epi int not null,
totOvos smallint,
num_pos smallint, 
num_inst smallint,
ipo decimal(5,1),
ido decimal(5,1),
ano varchar(4),
primary key(id_leste)) default charset = utf8;

-- OESTE--
create table tb_indices_oeste(
id_oeste int not null auto_increment,
localidade varchar(30),
sem_epi int not null,
totOvos smallint,
num_pos smallint, 
num_inst smallint,
ipo decimal(5,1),
ido decimal(5,1),
ano varchar(4),
primary key(id_oeste)) default charset = utf8;
```

Como devo proceder para fazer um SELECT que me retorne a SUM(totOvos), SUM(num_pos), SUM(num_inst) entre as 4 tabelas WHERE ano = 'X' AND sem_epi BETWEEN 'Y' AND 'Z' GROUP BY sem_epi

Sou iniciante em SQL, sei que devo definir as PRIMARY KEYS e as  FOREIGN KEY, o meu problema é justo esse, como definir nas tabelas e como criar esse SELECT.

Comment: Não poderia ser uma tabela e uma chave indicando o ponto cardeal (n s l o) !? Não entendi o modelo, confesso. Controla o que ? Pesquise por SELECT UNION pode ser uma saída

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Irei pesquisar mais sobe o UNION.

Answer (score 2):

Amiraldo observando seus esquema, como o Motta comentou, não é necessário criar 4 tabelas, basta você criar 2 onde uma armazena os dados NORTE, SUL, LESTE e OESTE (cada uma com sua respectiva ID) e a outra armazena os detalhes do dia, semana, mês, ano, necessário como você solicitou. Fiz um esqueminha aqui onde vc pode adota-lo ou modifica-lo ao seu gosto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo segue o Código:

Tabela Indices

```
CREATE TABLE Indices(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Indice NVARCHAR(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Tabela Detalhes

```
CREATE TABLE DetalhesDoDia(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    IndicesID INT NOT NULL,
    Localidade NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SemEPI SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Ovos SMALLINT,
    NumPos SMALLINT,
    NumInst SMALLINT,
    IPO DECIMAL(5,1),
    IDO DECIMAL(5,1),
    Ano NVARCHAR(4),

    CONSTRAINT FK_IndicesDoDetalhe
    FOREIGN KEY (IndicesID)
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Indices](ID)
)
GO
```

Select que retorna todos os dados

```
SELECT Indices.Indice, Detalhes.Localidade, Detalhes.SemEPI, Detalhes.Ovos, Detalhes.NumPos, Detalhes.NumInst, Detalhes.IPO, Detalhes.IDO, Detalhes.Ano
FROM [dbo].[DetalhesDoDia] AS Detalhes
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Indices] AS Indices
ON Detalhes.[IndicesID] = Indices.[ID]
GO
```

Select com a Soma

```
SELECT SUM(Detalhes.Ovos) AS 'Total OVOS', SUM(Detalhes.NumPos) AS 'Total POS', SUM(Detalhes.NumInst) AS 'Total INST'
FROM [dbo].[DetalhesDoDia] AS Detalhes
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Indices] AS Indices
ON Detalhes.[IndicesID] = Indices.[ID]
WHERE Detalhes.Ano = '2018'
AND Detalhes.SemEPI BETWEEN 0 AND 5
GROUP BY Detalhes.SemEPI
```

Comment: Vou estudar essa tua proposta. Obrigado, valeu mesmo!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, meu caro! Vou adicionar essas 2 tabelas no banco, se não vou ter que alterar as querys de toda a aplicação e não é pouca coisa rsrsrs(próximo projeto irei tentar criar um banco mais coeso.) Irei apenas implementar uns triggers e fica tudo certo! Obrigado mais uma vez pelo conhecimento compartilhado!